# Mongoose default filter/query params for find()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I have a collection of docs such as:

```
{
    type: 'post',
    text: 'example',
    status: 'private' // or 'public'
}
```

What kind of middleware or schema config can I use to make sure that by default, Model.find() only returns docs where `status != 'private'` ?

I don't want to have to have to redundantly query for `status != 'private'` every single time I query the collection.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try implement a wrapper method, e.g `findNonPrivate()`, to your model which you can then delegate to finding every document with `status` not equal to `"private"`. Something like this:

```
var Model = mongoose.model('Model', theSchema);
Model.findNonPrivate = function (q, callback) {
  q.status = q.status || {"$ne": "private"};
  this.find(q, callback);
}
```

You could then get what you want with `Model.findNonPrivate({}, callback)`.

Comment: Doesn't this always return everything, where status != private? I.e. it is ignoring the q argument as it is overwritten.

Comment: Yeah i think a better implementation would be to override the default find method and just use ```q.status = q.status || {"$ne": "private"}```

Comment: @RobMeeuwisse You are both correct, hadn't tested it. I've updated my answer, thanks.